# Release an object at the end of a Dataflow process

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have a TPL process that takes an object and broadcasts it to an unknown number of TransformBlocks (between 0 and 2).

I'd like to be able to do something with the object once the TransformBlocks are done working with it (specifically, "release" it into an object pool).

I can't just wait for the completion of the blocks, because I'm treating thousands of such objects through my TPL process.

I can't seem to find a solution, any idea?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the `BroadcastBlock` the object pool? Or you have some `BufferBlock` behind it, serving as object pool?

Comment: You could add a "Join" block (not an actual JoinBlock) to combine the output, calculate if all "instances" of the object have arrived and release it afterwards. If the number of paths is fixed, you could use reference counting. Perhaps even a `Dictionay<T,int>` to hold the number of received object instances. Once the reference count reaches the limit you want, you can release it and remove it from the dictionary

Comment: Are you using one of the .NET object pools perhaps?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias no, I actually have a first TransformBlock that produces the data objects, didn't think it was relevant.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I actually "don't know" how many targets are linked to the BroadcastBlock, so I can't simply count. Also no, it's a custom object pool.

Comment: @Kilazur you could use a reference counting mechanism in that case - each time that object is offered to a target, increase its reference count. Each time it reaches the "end" of the pipeline, decrement it, and release the object when the count reaches 0. Unfortunately, there's no  built-in RefCounter in .NET but the pattern is so common various .NET Core libraries implement it themselves. There's [an ongoing discussion on how to add deeper pooling and ref counting support](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/12296)

Comment: That Github issue points to at least two pool implementations with reference counting used by Roslyn. In your case though you need to increment the count each time a message is offered to a target, which means a custom block to replace `BroadCastBlock`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the ref-count approach would work only under the assumption that all target `TransformBlock`s will accept the object offered by the `BroadCastBlock`, before any of the `TransformBlock`s propagates the object downstream. Otherwise the object could be released prematurely. I don't know how safe it is to make this assumption. I doubt that the TPL Dataflow documentation offers explicitly this guarantee.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias that assumption can be made. The references will be released by a block *after the branches. In fact, even the final block of each branch. That's little different from now .NET's own pools work right now

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, the reference counting way seems to be a good fit for my case. If you want to answer with this, I'll accept it.